# Packed and unpacked arrays in SystemVerilog

Tags: fpga, verilog, system-verilog

I've been studying mixed arrays.  I ran the following code on vcs:

```
module tb;
  byte stack [2][4] ;
  initial begin
    
    foreach (stack[i])
    
    foreach (stack[i][j]) begin
  
      stack[i][j] = $random;
      
      $display("stack[%0d][%0d] = 0x%0h" , i, j, stack[i][j]);
      
    end
    
    $display("stack = %p" , stack) ;
    
    $display("stack[0][0][2] = 0x%0h" , stack[0][0][2]);
  
  end
endmodule
```

The console gives the following output :

```
Compiler version S-2021.09; Runtime version S-2021.09;  Oct 21 11:42 2022

stack[0][0] = 0x24
stack[0][1] = 0x81
stack[0][2] = 0x9
stack[0][3] = 0x63
stack[1][0] = 0xd
stack[1][1] = 0x8d
stack[1][2] = 0x65
stack[1][3] = 0x12

stack = '{'{36, -127, 9, 99}, '{13, -115, 101, 18}} 

stack[0][0][2] = 0x1
```

Questions:

1. Why are there **negative** values in stack {} ?
2. Why are the items arranged in a group of 4 in stack{} ?
3. Does declaring the **byte** data type automatically create an 8-bit packed array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `byte` data type is signed.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 6.11 *Integer data types*:

> 2-state data type, 8-bit signed integer

It is similar to the following declaration:

```
bit signed [7:0] stack [2][4] ;
```

The `%p` format specifier chooses to display some of the signed values as negative decimal.  When I run your code on the Cadence simulator, it displays them in hex notation.  Perhaps the behavior is not well defined:

```
stack = '{'{'h24, 'h81, 'h9, 'h63}, '{'hd, 'h8d, 'h65, 'h12}}
```

You get 2 groups of 4 because that is how you declared your array.

Answer (score 1):

`$random` generate a 32-bit random value and you are assigning it to an 8-bit signed byte. It gets truncated--if the resulting bit pattern represents a negative number,, that's what you get.

`%p` is a *pretty-print* format that uses an assignment pattern as its format. It is using using a signed decimal format for each number. SystemVerilog has arrays-of-arrays. You have declared an array with two elements, and each element has an array with four elements.

`%h` is an unsigned radix format.